# Mockito verify method called once

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I'm trying to use mockito to verify if method is called. Here is an example:

```
@Test
public void t(){
    InvokedFromTest ift = mock(InvokedFromTest.class);
    TestClass t = new TestClass();
    t.ift = ift;

    t.mm(new String(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).put("123".getBytes()).array()));
    verify(ift, times(1)).m("123");
}

private static class TestClass{
    public InvokedFromTest ift;
    public void mm(String s){ ift.m(s); }
}

private static class InvokedFromTest{
    public void m(String s){}
}
```

But when runnig `t()` I got the following exception:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
invokedFromTest.m("123");
-> at com.pack.age.TableRowIgniteProcessingLogicTest.t(TableRowIgniteProcessingLogicTest.java:62)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
invokedFromTest.m("123");
-> at com.pack.age.TableRowIgniteProcessingLogicTest$TestClass.mm(TableRowIgniteProcessingLogicTest.java:67)
```

Why? Why did I get this error? How to make this test work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allocating a byte buffer of length 4 while only 3 digits (each of length 1 byte) are stored. Passing this byte array to the constructor of String, creates a String of 4 characters where the last character is \u0000 (byte=0).

Use `ByteBuffer.allocate(3)`.

Comment: Hah, but why is another string produced? Very unclear message.

Comment: Because you're initializing the String with a byte array of length 4. The last byte remains zero. Try debugging the creation of the String, you'll see it's 4 characters long.